# Disk failure imminent

Tags: disk, disk-utility, smart

I have been using Win7 ubuntu 12.04 dual boot laptop and one day I got Disk failure imminent message in ubuntu.I have been using Win 7 since then for about 2 months now and havent experienced anything problematic but it is not letting me boot in Ubuntu.What should I do?

Comment: You should change your hard drive. At least use a diagnostic tool and check your drive, imminent failure means just what it says, that your disk is about to die.

Comment: How is "not letting me boot in Ubuntu" not problematic? What happens when you try? Could it be that the part of the hard disk containing Ubuntu already failed?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is initiated not by Ubuntu but by the HDD manufacturer's SMART (Self-Monitoring Analysis and Reporting Technology System). In all probability, it is what it says: you'll need to replace your HDD soon.

1) Backup your data. Just do it.

2) You can access the SMART reporting data: either use a Windows util (need to know your HDD brand) or run the "Disks" GUI utility from the Ubuntu Live DVD. Not sure knowing the exact problem will help though.